# Multiple OS at Kubernetes pod in GCP

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, chroot

We want to use multiple OS in VDI without using multiple VDI in GCP.
So can we put multiple OS on single pod using different mount path.
if yes, can we use **chroot** for switch OS.
How can we create disk from Image in GCP.

Comment: You can have multiple OS on Multi-OS cluster.

Comment: A container probably isn't allowed to chroot(2) at all, in part because it could be used to escape the container filesystem.  I'm not sure what use case you have in mind here that wouldn't be better met with multiple containers (probably in separate Kubernetes Deployments).

Comment: we need multiple os on single VDI. Because on basis requirement we can switch OS.

Answer (score -1):

A Pod can contain more than one container, usually because these containers are relatively tightly coupled.Having multiple containers in a single Pod makes it relatively straightforward for them to communicate with each other. They can do this using several different methods. One of them is shared volumes in a kubernetes pod.

**Shared volumes in a Kubernetes Pod** - A standard use case for a Kubernetes multi-container Pod with a shared Volume is when one container writes logs or other files to the shared directory, and the other container reads from the shared directory.

You can refer to the [link](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/multi-container-pods-and-container-communication-in-kubernetes/https://) written by Nick Chase for more information on how to run multiple containers in a single pod using different methods.

Docker containers do not rely on a **chroot environment.** Instead, they utilize Linux namespaces and other kernel features to provide process-level isolation and filesystem isolation, enabling efficient and secure containerization.While chroot can be used within a Docker container if needed, it is not the primary mechanism for achieving containerization or isolation.